# How do I invoke a function reference when passed as an argument

Tags: javascript, function

Here's some example code.

```
invoke(arr, Array.prototype.sort);

function invoke(arr, func){
    // invoke func on arr so that the resulting array is sorted.
}
```

Comment: @RamRajamony Hmmm, nope.

Comment: You're right - I glossed over the first line, showing how func could be Array.prototype.sort which needs "this".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
invoke(arr, Array.prototype.sort);

function invoke(arr, func) {
    func.call(arr);
}
```

The first argument of `Function.prototype.call()` will behave as `this` in the target function.

Answer (score 3):

Use Function.call:

```
func.call(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
invoke(arr, Array.prototype.sort);

function invoke(arr, func){
    func.call( arr );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to call it as a regular function.

```
function invoke(arr, func){
    func();
}
```